# WCF Data Services - How to write this Select LINQ Query

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF Data Service. I cannot use this format (Long story, proxy class in the middle)
I'm trying to write this LINQ query :

```
from w in je.Streets
where w.CityId == (int)cb_City.EditValue
select new
    {
      HebName = w.HebName,
      EngName = w.EngName,
      ID = w.StreetID
     }).ToList();
```

to something like this

```
ServiceEntities se = new ServiceEntities();
se.Streets.Where(s => s.CityId == (int)cb_City.EditValue).Select( ???????? ).ToList();
```

I have no success, I get

```
Error translating Linq expression to URI: Can only specify query options (orderby, where, take, skip) after last navigation.
```

Can someone help???

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
se.Streets.Where(s => s.CityId == (int)cb_City.EditValue)
              .Select(s => new { 
                    HebName = s.HebName,
                    EngName = s.EngName,
                    ID = s.StreetID
              }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
je.Streets.Where(w = > w.CityId == (int)cb_City.EditValue).Select(x => 
   new {
          HebName = x.HebName,
          EngName = x.EngName,
          ID = x.StreetID
 }).ToList();
```